# SQL 2 Tables, get counts on first, group by second

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm working in MS Access 2003.

I have Table with records of that kind of structure:

```
ID, Origin, Destination, Attr1, Attr2, Attr3, ... AttrX

for example:

1,  1000,   1100,        20,    M,     5 ...
2,  1000,   1105,        30,    F,     5 ...
3,  1001,   1000,        15,    M,     10 ...
...
```

I also have table which has Origin And Destination Codes Grouped

```
Code, Country, Continent
1000, Albania, Europe
1001, Belgium, Europe
...
1100, China,   Asia
1105, Japan,   Asia
...
```

What I need is to get 2 tables which would count records based on criteria related to attributes I specify but grouped by:
1. Origin Continent and Destination Continent
2. Origin Continent and Destination Country

for example:

Case 1.

```
Origin, Destination, Total, Females, Males, Older than 20, Younger than 20, ...
Europe, China,       300,   100,     200,   120,           180 ...
Europe, Japan,       150,   100,     50, ...
...
```

Case 2.

```
Origin, Destination, Total, Females, Males, Older than 20, Younger than 20, ...
Europe, Asia,        1500,  700,     800 ...
Asia,   Europe,      1200, ...
...
```

Can that be done in the way so I could add more columns/criteria easily enough?

Comment: In a similar situation I used a form that allowed the user to select criteria and built the queries in VBA. I am not sure that you will get a satisfactory sql-only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:

```
select count(1) as total ,t2.continent,t3.country,t1.attr1,t1.attr2,t1.attr3 ... t1.attrX from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.origin = t2.code
join table3 t3 on t1.destination = t3.code
group by t2.continent,t3.country,t1.attr1,t1.attr2,t1.attr3 ... t1.attrX 
order by total desc
```

Case 2:

```
select count(1) as total ,t2.continent,t3.continent,t1.attr1,t1.attr2,t1.attr3 ... t1.attrX from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.origin = t2.code
join table3 t3 on t1.destination = t3.code
group by t2.continent,t3.continent,t1.attr1,t1.attr2,t1.attr3 ... t1.attrX 
order by total desc
```

Comment: Please note that the tags include MS Access, SQL is a generic tag, so this particular answer requires MS Access SQL. The above will not work.

Comment: I don't see how can I apply criteria on attributes to get specific counts using this answer. also access throws syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: you should add your attributes in select and group by also , of course it will throw an error , there are ...-s in the statement

Answer (score 0):

You can join queries with queries, so this is a crosstab for Male/Female (attr2)

```
TRANSFORM Count(Data.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Data.Origin, Data.Destination, Count(Data.ID) AS Total
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.Origin, Data.Destination
PIVOT Data.Attr2;
```

This is ages:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Data.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Data.Origin, Data.Destination, Count(Data.ID) AS Total
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.Origin, Data.Destination
PIVOT Partition([Attr1],10,100,10);
```

This combines the two:

```
SELECT Ages.Origin, Ages.Destination, Ages.Total,
       MF.F, MF.M, Ages.[10: 19], Ages.[20: 29], Ages.[30: 39]
FROM Ages, MF;
```

As you can see, this could be easier to manage in VBA.